# What kind of operation increases (swap) cached memory?

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, io, operating-system

When I use "top" on my linux machine, I see

```
    Cpu (s): 0.1%us ...
    Mem:  32819132k total, 29611624k used,  3207508k free,   252836k buffers
    Swap: 33425404k total, 0k used,        33425404k free, 25433492k cached
```

What kind of operation increases (swap) cached memory (last item above), something like file, disk I/O? 
Any suggestion for the relative OS notion?